# Prove that $ (x+y)^n \le x^n +y^n$ with $x,y \ge 0 $ and $0 \lt n \le 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, substitution

I have no clue on this one so I hope you can help me out on this one.

Let $x,y \ge 0 $ and $0 \lt n \le 1$.
Then $$ (x+y)^n \le x^n +y^n$$

Comment: Divide by $y^n$ then remember (or prove) [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality).

Comment: Write the binomial expansion of the LHS, if you know how to for $n\in\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, and compare both sides.

Comment: $n$ doesn't look to be integer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This case is not compatible with "no clue on this one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since our inequality is symmetric, we can assume that $y\geq x$.

Also if $x=0$ so the inequality is obviously true.

Let $x>0$ and $y=tx$, where $t\geq1$.

Hence, we need to prove that $f(t)\geq0$, where $f(t)=t^n+1-(t+1)^n$.

But, $f'(t)=n\left(\frac{1}{t^{1-n}}-\frac{1}{(1+t)^{1-n}}\right)\geq0$.

Thus, $f(t)\geq f(1)=0$ and we are done!

Comment: Nice Arquady, can we prove it without derivative, If yes then plz explain here, Thanks

Comment: @juantheron See my proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990936 I think we can understand convexity and Karamata without derivative.