# inequality with power function

Tags: inequality

> Hello. Let $0<b\leq1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq1$, does this inequality hold?
>   $(n-1)^b \leq n^b-1$

Ive tried quite a few combinations of $n$ and $b$ and it seems to be true but I dont know how to prove it (if its true)

Comment: For $b=0.5$ and $n=2$ you get $\sqrt 1 \le \sqrt 2 - 1$, which is wrong.

Comment: It is the way around, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990936/is-this-inequality-true-x-y-alpha-x-alpha-y-alpha-for-pos.

Comment: alright thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is actually the other way around. You can consider the function
$$f(x)=(x-1)^b-x^b+1$$
well-defined for every $x\geq 1$. Then
$$f'(x)=b(x-1)^{b-1}-bx^{b-1}$$
and since $x\geq 1$ we have $0\leq x-1\leq x$ so that $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 1$ (here we use $b-1\leq 0$) Hence $f$ is increasing. Moreover
$$f(1)=0$$
so that $f(x)\geq 0$ for every $x\geq 1$ that is
$$(x-1)^b\geq x^b-1$$
for all $x\geq 1$, in particular if $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Either my above counter-example or your proof must be wrong...

Comment: Olivier your idea is good, but you maybe forgot that $b-1$ is negative. You might want to fix you proof starting the sign of $f'.$

Comment: True enough, I'll change it!